# React Js getting Image from AWS s3 URL

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, imagedecoder

I have 7URL's out of which sometimes of 3-4 are valid downloadable Images.. so before rendering the Images using **getPhotosList** function I check the Valid download URL using function **CheckValidImages**

```
const CheckValidImages = async () => {
if (!props.location.state.isVideoContent) {
  let getRecipeDetailWorkflowRead = {props.location.state.recipeDetailWorkflowRead};
  let recipePhotos = [];
  let sequence = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < getRecipeDetailWorkflowRead.recipePhotos.length; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = getRecipeDetailWorkflowRead.recipePhotos[i].path;
    await img
      .decode()
      .then(() => {
        getRecipeDetailWorkflowRead.recipePhotos[i].sequence = sequence + 1;
        recipePhotos.push(getRecipeDetailWorkflowRead.recipePhotos[i]);
        sequence = sequence + 1;
      })
      .catch((encodingError) => {});
  }
  getRecipeDetailWorkflowRead.recipePhotos = recipePhotos;
  setRecipeDetailWorkflowRead(getRecipeDetailWorkflowRead);
  setImageLoader(false);
} else {
  setRecipeDetailWorkflowRead(
    props.location.state.recipeDetailWorkflowRead
  );
}
};

const getPhotosList = () => {
if (recipeDetailWorkflowRead.recipePhotos !== undefined) {
  console.log(recipeDetailWorkflowRead.recipePhotos);
  var listItems = recipeDetailWorkflowRead.recipePhotos.map((el, i) => {
    return (
      <div
        key={i}
        className={['mr-1', Classes.imagediv].join(' ')}
        draggable='true'
        onDragEnd={dragEnd}
        onDragStart={dragStart}
        data-item={JSON.stringify(el)}
      >
        <img
          className={i === 0 ? Classes.card_img_first : Classes.card_img}
          src={el.path}
          alt='cardimg'
        />
        <div className={Classes.card_body}>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='mediaDescription'
            value={el.mediaDescription || ''}
            onChange={(event) => onAltTextChangehandler(event, i)}
            placeholder='Alt text'
            className={['form-control', Classes.img_alt_text].join(' ')}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div
      onDragOver={dragOver}
      className={['d-flex', 'flex-row', Classes.contain].join(' ')}
    >
      {listItems}
    </div>
  );
}
};
```

In CheckValidImage function **getRecipeDetailWorkflowRead.recipePhotos[i].path** has an Image path which I check if its valid or not. Now if the image is valid I try push it in recipePhotos and finally after all images path are checked I update the state setRecipeDetailWorkflowRead

But this seems much time consuming activity if the Image size is bigger. Can someone suggest any another alternate option where I can retrive the Images faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about react, but with fetch I think you could do a 'HEAD' request and check the headers without downloading the content:

```js
var url = 'https://nystudio107-ems2qegf7x6qiqq.netdna-ssl.com/img/blog/_1200x630_crop_center-center_82_none/craft-cms-custom-field-leveraging-platform-2.jpg?mtime=1598495914';
var p = fetch(url, { method: 'HEAD' });
p.then(r => {
  if (r.status === 200 && r.headers.get('content-type') === 'image/jpeg')
  {
    console.log('Found an image!  Size is:', r.headers.get('content-length'));
  }
});
```